# Is there a way to include a directory on build, without it being in the assets folder?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have an Angular 4 app that is embedded into a website. There are some shared files that are in the root of the server that I reference when embedded into the website. My issue is, I want to be able to reference those files that are on the server in my app when I am doing development so I copy that folder to the root of my angular app but when the app builds, that folder is not copied.

For example I have a folder called `/media` in my root on the same level as the `/src` folder. When I do an `ng build` or if I just save and view my app locally, the media app is not copied so I am not able to see it. Adding it to the `/assets` folder is not an option so I am trying to figure out how to copy additional files on build.

I have tried a setup in my angular.cli.json file like this:

`"assets": [
  "assets",
  "../media",
  "favicon.ico",
  "favicon-test.ico",
  "../favicon-test-2.ico"
],`

and when I run ng build I only see 
assets, favicon.ico and favicon-test.ico
but I do NOT see the media directory or favicon-test-2.ico file.

Comment: You've tagged this with the CLI, so have you tried adding `"../media"` to the `assets` array in `.angular-cli.json`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe that would be exactly what I would want to be able to do. I tried adding ../media like you suggested but I do not see it in my dist folder after I run ng build. I only see the items that are in the src folder when I try adding paths to the assets array.

Comment: Actually, I'm sorry I'm a idiot. Previous developer had the media folder outside of the src folder I just assumed it needed to be there. I moved it to inside the src folder and was able to just say:

["assets", "media"]

bone head move. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add custom folders to build by adding path in

**Angular 5**

Filename: `.angular.cli.json`

```
"apps": [
  {
    "root": "src",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "assets": [
      "assets",
      "myFolder2/", // custom folders 1
      "myfolder2/", // custom folders 2,
      "file.json"   // custom files
    ],
  }
]
```

**Angular 6**

Filename: `angular.json`

```
"architect": {
  "build": {
    "options: {
       "assets": [
         "assets",
         "myFolder2/", // custom folders 1
         "myfolder2/", // custom folders 2,
         "file.json"   // custom files
        ]
     }
   }
 }
```

the files and folders mentioned in assets array will be added to `dist` folder when you run `ng build`

Comment: man this is the first time I've ever accepted an answer, that grey checkmark is bad UX in my opinion! lol thanks @Sibiraj

Comment: Is it just goind to copy the files to the dist folder, or will it transpile .ts files as well?

Comment: @BrunoSantos these should just be static asset files, so they just get copied during build, not transpiled. its similar to if you did a copy in webpack.